# Please help me to fix this Touch Bar problem

Tags: ventura, touch-bar

I've set Touch Bar to show App Controls and Control Strip when I hold the fn key, but I've set it to show F1-F12 keys for several applications.

Previously In those applications, I could hold the fn key to show me Control Strip instead of F1-F12 and it was so convenient, but now holding the fn key is not working anymore, Touch Bar constantly showing F1-F12 and I don't know how to get that fn key behaviour back.

Please help me to fix this Touch Bar problem...

Here are 10 seconds video fragment of how it worked before (F1-F12 switch to Control Strip when you hold the fn key): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU2eqKO-Fz4&t=46s.

Answer (score 0):

For this, open **System Preferences > Keyboard > Touch Bar Settings**. It will open a popup window.

Then, set the "**Touch bar shows**" parameter to "**Expanded Control Strip**". Then, set the "**Press and hold fn key to**" parameter to "**Show F1, F2, etc. Keys**". Then click on "**Done**".

[image]

It will show the Expanded Control Strip normally, when you press the <kbd>fn</kbd>, it will show the F1-F12 options on the Touch Bar

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem. The fn key doesn't switch F1-F12 to Control Strip.

Comment: @DmitryShepelenko I edited to fit with your case (I was mistaken).

Comment: Thank you again, but this is for the regular use case. For the regular use case, the fn key works.

IDK if I managed to put it clearly, but the problem is with those applications I set to show F1-F12 keys (System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Function Keys).

Previously the fn key worked for them too.

Comment: @DmitryShepelenko I still fail to see what you need if it's not what I proposed, it should apply to all apps.